# How to move files to another destination folder with modified date at the end of which will be moved files

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, osx-yosemite

I am using  Mac OS x 10.10 terminal & bash 3.2.57(1)-release. 
I want to move all, but 3 most recent files. 
Also, all the moved files should have modified date at the end of file name (not the current time, but the last modified date of every file).

For example :

before: `aaaa12345.mp4`

after: `aaaa_20150405_200834.mp4`

Following statement moves all, bust latest 3 files

```
mv -f $(ls -1t /Users/home/test/mv/* | tail -n +4) /Users/home/test/*
```

Questions is:

How to add modified date and remove 12345 at the end of all file names (except for latest 3 files), before moving?

Comment: Is it always "12345"? Is it alwys 5 digits? You need to be more specific about your files.

Comment: You're going to need to use the `stat` command. Check its man page.

Comment: hi. not always 12345 , this mean need to be removed several characters not only number.

Comment: How many to remove: specify it!

Comment: hi again. thanks your reply.  ok let me specify without 12345.  you can go without 12345.  only aaaa